How to place an arrayplot/image on a GeoGraphics?
Take a random example data matrix
data = Table[i, {i, 100}, {j, 200}] / 100;

which we could plot as an ArrayPlot or Image
im = Image[Map[ColorData["Rainbow"], data, {2}]]


What I want is to project that on a GeoGraphics such that it properly stretches and projects to fills a 4 sided GeoPolygon.
Say this polygon
gpol = GeoPolygon[GeoPosition /@ {{-50.55, -55.56}, {-11.12, -10.139},  {-4.51, -18.77}, {-41.20, 63.33}}];

GeoGraphics[gpol]


I saw there's GeoStyling, but I don't get how to have it do the rotating and stretching
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", im}], gpol}]


Note how this is not the desired result but instead its like a texture that doesn't transform to align to the GeoPolygon borders.
What's the proper way to do this? To generally plot an array of values over the surface of the globe? I have no problem giving the GeoPosition where I want every pixel to be mapped to if necessary.
EDIT:
I'm trying with GeoDensityPlot and finding a pretty ugly solution that takes forever and doesn't look that great where I pass all the geolocations of the points and the values as 1D vectors in GeoDensityPlot[geolocs -> vals], and also add a RegionFunction-> option that uses RegionMember (is there nothing like GeoRegionMember??) to check whether a given latitude and longitude falls within the desired GeoPolygon, which I first convert to a Polygon by going through each side and sampling the geodesics at many points with GeoDestination. Blergh.
Maybe there's something decent to be done with GeoDensityPlot -that doesn't take tens of minutes for each plot- but I'm still struggling to find it.
Side question that would make this horribly slow solution a bit less horribly slow: is there a quick way to check if a geoposition is inside a GeoPolygon?

This seems to work. I replaced GeoPolygon with Polygon and also used VertexTextureCoordinates.
data = Table[i, {i, 100}, {j, 200}]/100;
im = Image[Map[ColorData["Rainbow"], data, {2}]];
gpol = Polygon[
   GeoPosition /@ {{-50.55, -55.56}, {-11.12, -10.139}, {-4.51, -18.77}, {-41.20, -63.33}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}];
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"Image", im}], gpol}]



I am not sure why it works with GeoStyling[{"Image", im}] but not with GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", im}].
With GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", im}] it produces wrong projection.

With GeoGraphics[{Texture[im], gpol}] instead of  GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"Image", im}], gpol}] the scaling with data[[All, ;; 50]] = 0.5; is correct but on other hand the colors are affected like if some opacity was changed. Very strange behavior, maybe a bug in Mathematica.


Something else doesn't work with this... Add the line data[[All, ;; 50]] = 0.5; so that a fourth of the image should become green along its length. Then the plot shows a much shorter green band than it should.

Yes, I will probably delete the answer, as it does not work properly. It was just a try.

@Rojo See another variant, which solves one problem but adds another one.
